# Reindex or reorder group

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a clean way to reorder the index in a group.
Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mydates = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=1000, freq='D')
myts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(mydates)), index=mydates)
grouped = myts.groupby(lambda x: x.timetuple()[7])
mymin = grouped.min()
mymax = grouped.max()
```

The above gives me what I want, aggregate stats on julian day of the year BUT I would then like to reorder the group so the last half (183 days) is placed in front of the 1st half.
With a normal numpy array:

```
myindex = np.arange(1,367)
myindex = np.concatenate((myindex[183:],myindex[:183]))
```

But I can't do this with the groupby it raises a not implement error.

*Note: this is a cross post from [google-groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pydata/XS_nEy853aw). Also I have been reading on comp.lang.python, unfortunately people tend to ignore some posts e.g. from google groups.*

Thanks in advance,
Bevan

Comment: Do you want to reorder `mymin`/`mymax` or reorder each subset of data within the groupby object? From the title it seems like it's the latter but the `np.concatenate` example make it seem like the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just reindex the result?

```
In [7]: mymin.reindex(myindex)
Out[7]: 
184   -0.788140
185   -2.206314
186    0.284884
187   -2.197727
188   -0.714634
189   -1.082745
190   -0.789286
191   -1.489837
192   -1.278941
193   -0.795507
194   -0.661476
195    0.582994
196   -1.634310
197    0.104332
198   -0.602378
...
169   -1.150616
170   -0.315325
171   -2.233139
172   -1.081528
173   -1.316668
174   -0.963783
175   -0.215260
176   -2.723446
177   -0.493480
178   -0.706771
179   -2.082051
180   -1.066649
181   -1.455419
182   -0.332383
183   -1.277424
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of a specific Pandas function for this, but you could consider the np.roll() function:

```
myindex = np.arange(1,367)
myindex = np.roll(myindex, int(len(myindex)/2.))
```